# why node ref not saved in hook_node_presave

Tags: nodes

I have a node reference in my custom content type, It can get some content type as reference in unlimited ,
I want to programmatically  add nodes to it ,

some part of my code is

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
.....

$nid_res=_convert_smarttag($body, 2);
ym($node,'message');
foreach($nid_res as $i=>$val ){
      $node->field_news_tags['und'][$i]=$val->nid;
      // ym($i .'=='.$val->nid,'message');
        }
ym($node,'message'); 
.....
}
```

before my `foreach`

[image]

in my foreach
[image]

and after foreach
[image]

I check this nid , it's type checked to be referenced in this field.
**but I dont know why this not saved finally !!!where is my problem?**

Comment: wild guess it's a string and not an integer?

Comment: @Jimajamma I try `intval($val->nid)`  but also not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake ,maybe useful for others that want save nid programmatically

```
foreach($nid_res as $i=>$val ){
      $node->field_news_tags['und'][$i]['nid']=$val->nid;
      // ym($i .'=='.$val->nid,'message');
        }
```